# Pandas .diff() on specific rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have seen many similar questions but none of them solves my problem.

I have a very large dataset where I want to find difference for only a few selected rows from the previous row. In the fol example, I would like to get diff() on pVal based on the value in calc, as shown:

```
     pVal        calc        pDiff
1    .17         False       NaN
2    .31         False       NaN
3    .46         False       NaN
4    .39         True       -.07
5    .26         False       NaN
6    .6          True       .34
```

Note: pDiff gets NaN by default

One can simply calculate the difference for all the rows and later replace pDiff with NaN against False under 'calc'. But as stated earlier, I have a very large dataset with very few 'True' values in the calc column, so lots of overhead.

I have tried the following:

```
df['pDiff'] = df[df['calc']==True]['pVal'].diff()
```

But it gives incorrect results, calculating difference between the rows with calc==True. In our example, the difference for row 6 is computed between rows 6 and 4 (0.6 - 0.39 = 0.21), instead of expected 0.34 between rows 6 and 5. Difference for row 4 remains NaN being the first row with calc==True.

I have the option to iterate through all the rows but that is too slow for me.

I need a solution that calculates and changes values for only those rows where calc contains True.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run: `df['pDiff'] = np.where(df.calc, df.pVal.diff(), np.nan)`.

`df.pVal.diff()` is the source of data and `np.where` acts as a filter.
`df.calc` is the condition and `np.nan` is the "other" value.

Answer (score 1):

`np.where` + `shift` are great together for previous or next row comparison based on conditions :)

```
df['pDiff'] = np.where((df['calc'] == True), df['pVal'] - df['pVal'].shift(), np.nan)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
df['shifted'] = df.calc.shift()
df1 = df[(df.calc == True) | (df.shifted == True)]
df1.pdidff = df1.pVal.diff()
```